# How does Xcode server run tests in release mode without Enable Testability?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcode-server

When using Xcode server to execute UI Tests, the bot has a setting to 'override' the configuration to Release mode.

This was handy as tests would be executed on release build.

Now when I am trying to run tests on TeamCity or CLI and pass the `-configuration Release` I get an error saying `Module 'App name' was not compiled for testing`

This can be solved by toggling `Enable testability` flag for Release configuration in build settings but that will have to be changed back each time before releasing the app.

Creating another build configuration is also not a desirable option as I have a lot of targets and maintaining an extra config for all would be a pain.

So how does Xcode server do this? Is there a CLI param or something I am missing? Or does it just change the setting via a prebuild script?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Smartcat Hey not really. Worked around this by using `update_xcodeproj` fastlane plugin to update the value before building on CI if that helps.